# Looping through columns of csv-file in R

Tags: r, for-loop

This probably is an easy question, but I'm just starting learning how to use R.

I have a csv-file filled with columns containing numbers. For every column of numbers I want R to conduct a Shapiro-Wilks test of normality. So, I want to loop through the columns from left to right, as to conduct `shapiro.test(file$column1), shapiro.test(file$column2)`, etc.

All columns have a name as their header, and they don't contain the same number of rows.

How do I go about? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
apply(file, 2, shapiro.test)
```

and take a look at `?apply`

Another way is using `sapply`

```
sapply(file, shapiro.test, simplify=FALSE)
```

also take a look at `?sapply`

An example using `airquality` dataset

```
> data(airquality)
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6

# Applying shapiro.test function
> Test <- apply(airquality, 2, shapiro.test)

# Showing results in a nice format
> sapply(Test, function(x) unlist(x[c( "statistic", "p.value")]))
                   Ozone      Solar.R      Wind        Temp        Month          Day
statistic.W 8.786661e-01 9.418347e-01 0.9857501 0.976173252 8.880451e-01 9.531254e-01
p.value     2.789638e-08 9.493099e-06 0.1178033 0.009320041 2.258290e-09 5.047775e-05

> sapply(Test, function(x) c(x["statistic"], x["p.value"])) # same results as above
          Ozone        Solar.R      Wind      Temp        Month       Day         
statistic 0.8786661    0.9418347    0.9857501 0.9761733   0.8880451   0.9531254   
p.value   2.789638e-08 9.493099e-06 0.1178033 0.009320041 2.25829e-09 5.047775e-05
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I noticed this only works when there are no columns where all the numbers are the same (for example a column that only contains ones). Otherwise this happens: _Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : all 'x' values are identical_.
Is there way to tell R to skip these columns, so it doesn't result in an error?

Comment: Yes there is a way to tell R to skip those colums, use the indexing functions `[`. Take a look at `?"["`. For skipping column 3 from `file` just do `file[, -3]`.